# How to configure AWS config to send compliance change notification to SNS topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, monitoring, amazon-sns, aws-config

AWS doc given [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/example-config-rule-compliance-notification.html) mentions that we can configure this notification to be sent to SNS topic but I am not able to find steps or tutorial to configure aws config to send this notification.

**What I have already tried:**

Cloudwatch alarm to SNS - does not support AWS config.

Eventbridge rules - not sure if this is the correct approach to get the notifications from config.

Comment: does this doc help?  what is missing here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/config-resource-non-compliant/

Comment: There has to more simpler ways of sending notifications to SNS without having to integrate it with the event bridge. Plus, I want to receive the compliance notification exactly in the format as mentioned in the example given in the link and not in the message format as evaluated by the event bridge

Answer (score -1):

That link are the example notifications that are sent to the SNS component of your AWS Config Delivery channel.  To setup your delivery channel including the S3 Bucket and SNS Topic that AWS Config will use to send configuration status to, follow the guide below:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/manage-delivery-channel.html

This periodically delivers the status of every AWS Config Rule.

Note: You can only have one delivery channel per region per account.  You can't create multiple channels so if you update this you'll be updating it for everything in your region.

If you want to just be notified when a specific AWS Config rules or set of rules are non-compliant, [you can setup an Event Bridge rule to send a message to an SNS topic when that event is found](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/config-resource-non-compliant/).

Comment: There has to more simpler ways of sending notifications to SNS without having to integrate it with the event bridge. Plus, I want to receive the compliance notification exactly in the format as mentioned in the example given in the link and not in the message format as evaluated by the event bridge.

Comment: is the use case for receive a specific set of resources?  Do you have SNS configured in your AWS Config delivery channel like mentioned in the first part of the answer?